# Set iPhone photo resolution default

Tags: iphone, photos, resolution

I need to take photos and upload them in a web page. A resolution of 800x600 would be enough for me.

I go to Settings > Photos & Camera, but I can only find a configuration for the resolution of the video recording, but not the Photos.

Anyone know if there is any way to take photo with the camera in low resolution?

I'm looking to avoid having to use an external app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change my iPhone's camera's resolution?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368579/how-can-i-change-my-iphones-cameras-resolution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to define the resolution of the photos in the camera settings.